# Laravel Error screen debugging

Tags: php, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04, linode

I just moved my Laravel app from local to production but I am continuously seeing **Whoops, Looks like somethig went wrong** when I go there. I have tried generating key and I have also set `debug=>true` in /config/app.php
I tried to `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` but there was not error regarding this.
permissions on `storage/` are 775 and owner is `www-data:www-data`
How can I debug this app.
Laravel version is 5.2
Server is Linode

Comment: try to change the debug mode in .env file of your project also and then check

Comment: Try checking storage/logs/laravel.log?

Comment: @rahul in .env, debug mode is also set to true

Comment: @SteD I don't have laravel.log file there on that location